# Universal image loader is loading blurry image sometimes

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using UIL in a listview, the images are getting loaded fine but I noticed sometimes it's loading a blurred image, below is what I'm doing,

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder( context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache( new WeakMemoryCache());

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
 ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

And below is my listview

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final ImageView image = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (new File(mediaUrl).exists()) {
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + mediaUrl, image);


    }


 }
```

XML

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: remove this line from your options and try again .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: post your listview row xml code please